# There should be a strange bug,what is that?

Tags: java

Both probabilities have the same code,but when i want to make addition,the text "enter the first number" is not shown. What did i do false?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class berketurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int command1;
        int number1;
        int number2;
        int result;
        System.out.print("for subtraction,press 1.for addition,press 2.");
        command1=input.nextInt();
        if (command1==1)
            System.out.print("enter the first number:");
            number1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("enter the second number:");
            number2=input.nextInt();
            result=number1-number2;
            System.out.printf("the result is=%d\n",result);
        if (command1==2)
            System.out.print("enter the first number;"); //here is the problem
            number1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("enter the second number;");
            number2=input.nextInt();
            result=number1+number2;
            System.out.printf("the result is=%d\n",result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `{}` braces from your if statement bodies, all you have is the indentation (which doesn't work since Java isn't Python).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class berketurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int command1;
        int number1;
        int number2;
        int result;
        System.out.print("for addition,press 1.for subtraction,press 2.");
        command1=input.nextInt();
        if (command1==1) { // <-- opening
            System.out.print("enter the first number:");
            number1=input.nextInt();  // <- your code stops here
            System.out.print("enter the second number:");
            number2=input.nextInt();
            result=number1-number2;
            System.out.printf("the result is=%d\n",result);
        } // <-- closing
        if (command1==2) { // <-- opening
            System.out.print("enter the first number;"); //here is the problem
            number1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("enter the second number;");
            number2=input.nextInt();
            result=number1+number2;
            System.out.printf("the result is=%d\n",result);
    } // <-- closing
}
```

}

You forgot the opening and closing of each block. So the first print is not executed and your code stops waiting for input.